# Play's trying to apply all dows evolutions while creating new Play 2.6 project with an existing database

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

I currently have a Play 1.2.7 application running in production, with an existing Postgresql database. I'm about to migrate my whole application to Play 2.6.

I read most of the [Play framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/fr/2.4.x/Home) but I can't find a solution to my problem.

The fact is I only added my existing [evolutions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/fr/2.4.x/Evolutions) (1.sql -> 178.sql) to the project, without any models at the moment.

IMPORTANT FACT : I just found that there is a "hole" in the evolution scripts. We have scripts from 1.sql to 107.sql and from 111.sql to 178.sql. The 108, 109 and 110 scripts are missing (historical mistake I guess by the dev team).

The play_evolutions table of the database is consistent with this hole. There's no rows with id 108, 109 or 110.

When running my hello world Play 2.6 app, Play wants to apply all ths downs and then only apply ups from 1 to 107. This is a problem because it would erase all my data, and it seems that the hole stops the ups to 107.sql.

My question is : Is the problem due to the hole in scripts or to the fact that I didn't integrate the models yet ? How can I do to make Play accept this hole, or to fill it manually.

My evolutions are in conf/evolutions/default

Here are my main configuration files :

1) conf/application.conf

```
## Secret key
play.crypto.secret = "changeme"

## Internationalisation
play.i18n {
  langs = [ "fr" ]
}

## JDBC Datasource
db {
    default.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    default.url = "postgres://user:password@localhost:5432/databasename"
    default.jndiName=DefaultDS
}

ebean.default = ["models.*"]

# Number of database connections
# See https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing
fixedConnectionPool = 9

# Set Hikari to fixed size
play.db {
  prototype {
    hikaricp.minimumIdle = ${fixedConnectionPool}
    hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}

# Job queue sized to HikariCP connection pool
database.dispatcher {
  executor = "thread-pool-executor"
  throughput = 1
  thread-pool-executor {
    fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
  }
}
```

2) build.sbt

```
name := """my-app"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.12.4"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.2.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(evolutions, jdbc)


// Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that generated 
.scala or .class files for views and routes are present
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile, compile in Test)


PlayKeys.devSettings += "play.server.http.port" -> "80"
```

3) project/plugins.sbt

```
// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.6.15")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "5.2.4")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "4.1.3")
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

I just removed all the scripts (the ~178 *.sql files) from the conf/evolutions folder. I also removed all the rows in the play_evolutions table of my database.

Finally I added a 1.sql empty file (without it Play generates automatically DDL scripts based on the models)

So, migrating my application, I started a new Play 2.6 project, lost all my past evolutions and kept my data.

Maybe it is now the best way to do, but if it can help someone !

Answer (score 0):

You can add play.evolutions.autoApplyDowns=false in application.conf to tell play to not apply down script

this is advised in production